# Yii2 urlmanager with many params

Tags: php, yii2, yii-url-manager

Now I have urlManager like this:

```
'art/list' => 'ask/index',
'art/list/sort/<sort:\w+>/' => 'ask/index',
'art/list/sort/<sort:\w+>/type/<type>' => 'ask/index',
```

And have link:

```
/art/list/sort/new/type/pro+local+buisnes+tourist
```

How can I configuration urlManager for more parameters without so many declaring it in urlManager(For example if I have 10 or 20 params)?

Comment: What about getting a single `type` variable and processing it later? i.e. `explode("+", $type)`

Comment: @gmc But if i want have link like this /art/list/sort/new/type/pro+local+buisnes+tourist/country/canada/city/toronto/something/param